# Общие статичные файлы и общий шаблон в Django

Tags: django

При создании сайта, в котором фигурируют несколько приложений, столкнулся со следующей проблемой: у сайта должен быть общий дизайн, соответственно, и общие статические файлы, и некоторый общий базовый шаблон, от которого идут наследоваться все остальные. Вопрос, собственно, и заключается в том, куда общие статические файлы (jQuery.js, например) положить, и куда базовый шаблон?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из самых часто используемых вариантов: в корне проекта каталоги templates и static. Они и содержат базовый шаблон и общие статические файлы.

Другой часто используемый вариант: создаётся главное приложение, и базовый шаблон и общие статические файлы принадлежат главному приложению. По мне так этот вариант даже более предпочтителен, поскольку в главном приложении можно содержать кроме шаблонов и статики ещё некие общие функции и тэги.

Comment: Так, тогда другой вопрос: вот у меня уже есть пара равноправных приложений, как мне создать для них супер-приложение?

Comment: точно так же, как и любое другое приложение: python manage.py startapp main

Comment: Если у меня база лежит в main/templates/main/base.html, a наследник в blog/templates/blog/post.html, то как мне в наследнике путь к базе указать?

Comment: {% extends "main/base.html" %}

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: Всё замечательно, только favicon почему-то не грузится.

Comment: а как вы его грузите? Есть варианты: либо в url.py его прописать, либо в шаблоне:

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "main/images/favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static "main/images/favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">

Comment: Видимо, комментарии закончились.

Я фавикон грузил через шаблон, только он у меня лежал не в `'main/images/favicon.png'`, а в `'main/favicon.png'`. Хотя путь был прописан правильно, он всё равно не грузился, но как только поменял папку -- всё заработало. 

Ну и вопрос для общего развития: как его в `urls.py` прописать?

Comment: да, здесь ограниченное количество комментариев возможно.

тэг static находит те лишь файлы, пути к которым в settings.py прописаны. Не в этом ли дело?

В url.py примерно так прописать:

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=путь_к_фавиконке), name='favicon'),
    )